# Calling new JsonFactory() causes android app crash java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, jackson

I am using jackson-core.jar(2.4.2) in my android application. I included the jackson-core.jar(2.4.2) in
the build path.

When calling new JsonFactory() there is a crash: NoClassDefFoundError exception

Can anyone please help me in this.

Logcat output

> 12-10 23:45:54.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6287): FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   IntentService[FileTransferService] 12-10 23:45:54.446:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(6287): Process: com.quest.socialapp, PID: 6287 12-10
>   23:45:54.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6287): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory 12-10 23:45:54.446:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(6287):   at
>   com.quest.socialapp.JsonFileGenerationManager.(JsonFileGenerationManager.java:17)
>   12-10 23:45:54.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6287):   at
>   com.quest.socialapp.FileTransferService.onHandleIntent(FileTransferService.java:48)
>   12-10 23:45:54.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6287):   at
>   android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
>   12-10 23:45:54.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6287):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 12-10
>   23:45:54.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6287):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 12-10 23:45:54.446:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(6287):   at
>   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Comment: Make sure jackson-core.jar is exported in your .classpath file

Comment: Yes I verified it, its there

Comment: Perhaps Proguard is stripping it out

Comment: Is your jar file in your project libs folder?

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project and try again.

Comment: Did you verify that the classpathentry has an exported="true" attribute as well as being present in the .classpath file for the jar?

Comment: Yea.I fixed the issue. It was due the order and export in which the jackson core jar was below the src. Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due the order and export in which the jackson core jar was below the src. I just brought jackson core jar before src.